# Java dynamic webserver - unable to read 'hello world' jersey resource

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey-2.0

Im using jersey 2.0 and i have installed jersey jar files into eclipse using this [site](https://jersey.java.net/download.html)

the issue i am having is i cannot load a hello world project.

here is my project structure:

[image]

and here is the web.xml located in WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>com.vogella.web.filecounter2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.vogella.web.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.web.filecounter2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and here is the hello world class:

```
 package com.vogella.web.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }

}
```

The issue i am having is when i run the server it says resource not found. Here is the link:

```
http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.web.filecounter2/rest/hello
```

UPDATE: Here is a list of all jar files i have:

[image]

and here is the error i get when it try to view the resource either in eclipse or on chrome:

[image]

Comment: Could you tell what all libraries file (jars) you have included as resources for your project?

Comment: i updated the question showing all the jars

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that the URL that you enter should contain the name of the WAR file that you deploy into the Apache Tomcat. Supposing your WAR file is named `test`, then the URL should be of the type
`http://localhost:8080/test/custom/url`. One way to test that the deployment is successful is by having a simple HTML file in your `webapp` folder, and then trying to access it as `http://localhost:8080/test/index.html`. If this works, then you can be sure that the problem is not in the deployment.

Comment: I will try your code after sometime if the question still doesn't have an answer, will post updates if I come to some conclusion.

Comment: The 
`<init-param>
        <param-name>com.vogella.web.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.vogella.web.filecounter2</param-value>
 </init-param>`
looks wrong. The `param-name` should be something like `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` and your `param-value` should be what your current `param-name` is.

Comment: this is the right answer. it works.  You can post a solution if your interested in points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your `web.xml` needs a correction.

```
<init-param> 
    <param-name>com.vogella.web.resources</param-name> 
    <param-value>com.vogella.web.filecounter2</param-value> 
</init-param>
```

The `param-name` and `param-value` fields are not correct. Change the `param-name` to `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` and `param-value` to `com.vogella.web.resources`.

The correction should look like

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.vogella.web.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```